# Custom MKAnnotation not showing up on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

So I am trying to add a custom annotation to my mkmap view. I have traced it down to an issue in my custom annotation class (see below). Does anyone see an issue with my code?

//// .h file /////

```
@interface AddressAnnotation : MKAnnotationView 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;


-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord andAddress:(NSString *)address;

@end
```

/// .m ///////////

```
@implementation AddressAnnotation

@synthesize image = _image;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {

return [self initWithCoordinate:coord andAddress:nil];

}


-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord andAddress:(NSString *)address {

if (self = [super init]) {
    self.coordinate = coord;
    self.address = address;
}
return self;
}



@end
```

I should also state that I tried this in my .h but it didn't help.

```
@interface AddressAnnotation : MKAnnotationView <MKAnnotation>
```

Also I know its the code in my annotation, because I changed the type of annotation to one I know works and it places it on the map.

=== UPDATE ================
More code per your request.

Below are two examples of my viewForAnnotation code. The top one is what is *NOT* working and the bottom *IS* working.

/// does NOT work/////

```
else if([annotation isKindOfClass:[AddressAnnotation class]]){

    static NSString *identifier = @"addressLocation";
    AddressAnnotation *addAnno = (AddressAnnotation *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!addAnno) {
        addAnno = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    addAnno.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map_pin.png"];
    addAnno.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 39); //initial bounds (default)
    return addAnno;
```

/// DOES work/////

```
else if([annotation isKindOfClass:[AddressAnnotation class]]){

    static NSString *identifier = @"addressLocation";
    HGMovingAnnotationView *addAnno = (HGMovingAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!addAnno) {
        addAnno = [[HGMovingAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    addAnno.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map_pin.png"];
    addAnno.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 39); //initial bounds (default)
    return addAnno;
}
```

Comment: What does the code in `viewForAnnotation` return for annotations of type AddressAnnotation?  Note that the _model_ class of your custom annotations is usually a subclass of NSObject (not MKAnnotationView).  MKAnnotationView is a generic class used for the _view_ of an annotation.  Also note that by default, MKAnnotationView returns an empty view.  Technically, a class can be both the model and view of an annotation but I wouldn't recommend it (if only to avoid confusion).

Comment: The MKAnnotationView and its MKAnnotation are not the same thing. It may work having an AnnotationView that serves as the Annotation itself but I doubt that is what the inventors had in mind. You may add 1000 annotations to the map but the map will request from its delegate views for those annotations only that are currently visible. It comes with a reuse-logic for the annotation views similar to the reusage of the cell views in tables.

Comment: Please show more code. Did you assign your view controller as MKMapViewDelegate to the MKMapView? If so how does your `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` implementation look like?

Comment: You should not be subclassing `MKAnnotationView`, but rather `MKAnnotation`. See the [Defining a Custom Annotation Object](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW2) in the _Location Awareness Programming Guide._

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is so I just made AddressAnnotation a subclass of one that works. The class below.

```
@interface HGMovingAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView

@interface AddressAnnotation : HGMovingAnnotationView
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another class AuxLocation in the example.

AuxLocation.h

```
 #import < Foundation/Foundation.h>

 #import < mapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface AuxLocation : NSObject
{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;

@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

Then the AuxLocation.m

```
**#import "AuxLocation.h"**

@implementation AuxLocation

@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;

@end
```

Then in the class that you want to show the annotation

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController
{

    AuxLocation *annotation;   


}
```

MyClass.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [super viewDidLoad];

    annotation = [[AuxLocation alloc] init];

    annotation.title=@"Antonella Pino Diseño Interior";

    annotation.coordinate=region.center;

    [mapview addAnnotation:annotation];   

}
```

Hope this result is useful.